# Is there a way to create a Ruby model scope for ordering books? (none numeric, none alphabetic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an app where there are quotes from books with notes or thoughts on the quotes. I want to list out the quotes in order of the book order, chapter order and then page order.

Is there a way to move this to a scope within the model in order to keep the ActiveRelation?

like

```
class Quote
  scope :sorted, ->(order_of_books|book|) { where("reference_book = ?", book) }
end
```

I have code like the following in my Controller that does the job of ordering the quotes by book order.

```
# /app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb

def quotes
    @quotes = Quotes.all
    @sorted_quotes = []
        
    order_of_books.each do |book|
        @temp_array = []
        if @quotes.any? { |quote| quote[:reference_book] == book}
            @temp_array << @quotes.detect { |quote| quote[:reference_book] == book}
            # @temp_array.sort_by! { |quote| quote.reference_paragraph, quote.reference_sentence }
            @sorted_quotes << @temp_array
        end
    end
end

# /app/models/concerns/book_concern.rb

def order_of_books
   [ 
    "Book A",
    "Book B",
    "Book C",
   ]
end
```

This is the database table for reference.

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "quotes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "text", null: false
    t.string "reference_book", null: false
    t.integer "reference_chapter", null: false
    t.integer "reference_paragraph", null: false
    t.integer "reference_sentence", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.text "notes"
end
```

**Errors**

The issue is now that I am trying to sort the quotes, all my other code is breaking when in my views when I try to call something like `quote.image` and I get this error:

`` undefined method `image' for [#<Quote id: 4, created_at: "2023-11-21 15:19:.... ``

**Side Note**

The line in my controller where I try to `sort_by!` the paragraph and sentence isn't working so I just commented it out. Right now that isn't as important for me.

`

Comment: Is the "book order" meant to be static (hardcoded), dynamic (passed in by the user), or actually just alphabetical (i.e. there's really no need to be so explicit about the names of books)?

Comment: There's several things I could say about improving your current method, however, *even if you were to improve the above method's implementation*, it would't make any difference to the error you mentioned about calling `quotes.image`: Because it seems you're actually trying to call the method on a **collection of quotes**, rather than a single `quote` (despite the misleadingly named variable). Instead, you'd need to use something like **`quotes.each { |quote| .... quote.image .... }`** to iterate over the list.

And thirdly,

Comment: @TomLord, The `quote.image` is on the view page for each individual quote where it shows the quote, the image that's associated and the note. There shouldn't be a need to iterate through the quote list for that. The time I am iterating through the quotes list is to sort the list by the static (hardcoded) book list to put the quotes in order of the book order; in my case the books are those in the Bible, and so I am following that order. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you answer my question above about the ordering? I can solve all three versions, but the code for a simple alphabetical ordering is much more straightforward, so I'd rather not over-engineer it.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that I had answered your question. The book order would be a static, hardcoded, order. Take for instance The Lord of the Rings and Prequel. The book order would be The Hobbit, The Fellowship of the Ring, The Two Towers, The Return of the King. Not alphabetical.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you may have multiple quotes per book (and will be adding more books over time - without wanting to add new lines to your code), you might want to normalise your data a little better by having a `books` table, storing the book `sort` field to capture the preferred sort order for the books (instead of that living in code directly);

```
# models/book.rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  validates :sort, presence: true
end

# models/quote.rb
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.string "author"
    t.integer "sort", null: false
end
create_table "quotes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "text", null: false
    t.bigint "book_id", null: false # < new column
    t.integer "reference_chapter", null: false
    t.integer "reference_paragraph", null: false
    t.integer "reference_sentence", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.text "notes"
    # TODO: you will also want a foreign key constraint here for quote.book_id
end
```

Then you could use this relationship to sort quotes, passing multiple columns to the [order](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) method - i.e. sort by `book.sort` first, then by `reference_chapter` (for any quotes in the same book), then by `reference_paragraph` (for any quotes in the same chapter) etc. As a best practice, I would suggest using `quotes.id` as a final disambiguator in case there were multiple quotes from the same book+chapter+paragraph+sentence.

```
# models/quote.rb
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  scope :sorted, -> { joins(:book).order('books.sort ASC, reference_chapter ASC, reference_paragraph ASC, reference_sentence ASC, id ASC') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. It does **not** answer my initial question of creating a `scope`, but it does solve the issue of my code not working for instances like `quote.image`

**Solution**

In my controller when I coded this:

```
@temp_array << @quotes.select { |quote| quote[:reference_book] == book}
@sorted_quotes << @temp_array
```

it would put the ActiveRelation inside an array element and then save it to the `@temp_array`; this is because `select` pulls all of the instances out of one array that matches the search terms. So, I just needed to undo this by iterating through the `@temp_array` and adding each element to the `@sorted_quotes` instead of adding the entire thing.

Here are my changes (also changing some variables to not be 'global' as that's just not needed in this situation.

```
def quotes
    quotes = Quote.all
    @sorted_quotes = []
    
    order_of_books.each do |book|
        temp_array = []
        if quotes.any? { |quote| quote[:reference_book] == book}
            temp_array << quotes.select { |quote| quote[:reference_book] == book}
            temp_array[0].each do |v|
                @sorted_quotes << v
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This fixed the issue. I can leave the question open as this solution does not technically answer the initial question about making a scope to do this same thing.

Comment: *In my controller when I coded this: `@temp_array << @quotes.select { |quote| quote[:reference_book] == book}`* -- **that's not the same code you shared in your original question** 

Comment: You are correct, I had originally posted with the `detect` in my OP which only pulls the first match. I forgot that I found that bug and fixed it before finding this workaround. 